# Query to get the listener.ora path in Oracle 11G

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, listener

Can anyone help me out with an PL/SQL query to get the path of the listener.ora file in Oracle 11G?

I require it to be fetched from the Oracle DB only via an SQL query & not via the Operating system's environment variables (Assuming ORACLE_HOME is not set & not known) or any Operating system command.

PS: I'm a DB newbie.

Answer (score 1):

The listener is an independent entity, can run from a different Oracle Home or even another machine. All the database knows about it is its address.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as the listener just handles the initial connection between the client and the database - so the database doesn't know anything about it.

So anyways there at least two  ways to get the path

1. Looking at the default locations (i.e. $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin)
2. fire up the OS-Command "lsnrctl status" and grep the path out of the output